# problems with array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert my notifications static , but I'm checking the variable type is not empty, but at the moment insert says `Message: Illegal string offset 'notificationCount'` and  `Undefined index: type`. I'm trying to make my array dynamically, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public function addNotification($message, $product_id, $type = ''){
    $types = array('new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 3);
    if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
    }
    $type = $types[$type];
    $time = time();
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id = ? AND type = ? ";
    $previousNotification = $this->db->query($query, array($product_id, $type));
    if ($previousNotification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $this->db->query($sql, array($message, $type, $product_id, $time));
        try {
            if ($this->db->query($sql)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

controller

```
public function add(){
        $this->notification->addNotification('low stock',4228,'type');
    }
```

Comment: Try [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), or use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) then compare with 0.

Comment: the same, it didnt work. the problem is in this line $type = $types[$type];

Answer (score 0):

`$sql_prev_notification` is a string that you've created here:

```
$sql_prev_notification = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id = ? AND type = ? ";
```

You use it to execute a query with:

```
$this->db->query($sql_prev_notification, array($product_id, $type));
```

but you haven't assigned the returned results of the query to anything.

`$sql_prev_notification` is still a string, so when you do this:

```
if ($sql_prev_notification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
```

`$sql_prev_notification[0]` is referring to the first letter in the string (`S`), which obviously isn't an array, hence the

> Illegal string offset 'notificationCount'

---

You probably want something more like:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS notificationCount FROM storelte_notifications WHERE product_id = ? AND type = ? ";
$sql_prev_notification = $this->db->query($sql, array($product_id, $type));
if ($sql_prev_notification[0]['notificationCount'] == 0) {
```

although you should also be checking if your query actually returns anything before referring to a specific item from its results.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Panic's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529550/4132627) is the right one to fix the illegal string offset, go with that.

For the error `Undefined index: type`, it would appear that you are passing the string "type" as the value for the variable `$type`. It then uses that value as a key for the `$types` array, but the `$types` array doesn't have an index "type" - its indexes are "new", "pending", and "low stock".

To fix this, you have to pass either "new", "pending", or "low stock" as the third parameter to your `addNotification` function:

```
$this->notification->addNotification('low stock',4228,'new');
//or
$this->notification->addNotification('low stock',4228,'pending');
//of
$this->notification->addNotification('low stock',4228,'low stock');
```

You should also check that the key passed is valid, otherwise you will continue to get this notice. In fact, passing the wrong value probably causes your code to function irregularly, in which case throwing an exception is probably a good idea:

```
if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
}

$type = $types[$type];
```

Comment: yeah , but I'm still getting Message: Illegal string offset 'notificationCount'

Comment: Like I wrote in the first sentence - to fix the illegal string offset part of your two-part question, go with Don't Panic's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43529550/4132627

Comment: by the way , Message: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysqli_result as array , why can I use result_array(); or result()? my bindings query is not getting result as an array

Comment: The documentation states that the `query()` function returns an object, not an array. To get your results as an array, call `result_array()` on your result object. Documentation is here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html. Note you are likely to see an error if no rows come back the way your `if` statement is currently constructed.

Comment: yes, if I havent rows I get an error like this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

INSERT INTO storelte_notifications (message,type,product_id,created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?), once I refresh the page and insert then I get what I wanted, but how can I fix it ?

Comment: I think at this point your original question has been answered by Don't Panic's answer and you should accept it as the right answer, and if you have further issues you can open a new issue to resolve the new issue with fresh answers instead of comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
public function addNotification( $message, $product_id, $type = '' ){
    $types = array( 'new' => 0, 'pending' => 1, 'low stock' => 3);
    if (isset($types[$type]) === false) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value for third parameter must be one of new, pending, or low stock.');
    }
    $type = $types[$type];
    $time = time();
    $this->db->select_sum('notificationCount');
    $this->db->where(['product_id' => $product_id, 'type' => $type]);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $previousNotification = $query->row_array()
    if ( $previousNotification['notificationCount'] == 0 ) {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->insert(storelte_notifications, ['message' => $message, 'type' => $type, 'product_id' => $product_id, 'created_at' => $time]);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return $this->db->trans_status();
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```